# Node http-middleware-proxy and express against Tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, express, tomcat

we are running our Java app (spring based) including the UI modules in a Tomcat container. Calling tomcat directly over http://localhost:8080 a login page is displayed and a redirect 302 occurs to the web app.
Now we want to develop the UI modules separately from the Java app by running an Express server with http-middleware-proxy and browser-sync. The modules have not been extracted out of the war-file and are running on the Tomcat instance. For testing purposes we just copied the UI module to another dir to setup Express and corresponding modules.
The problem is that we are not able to get the authorization cookies (JSESSIONID) and CSRF tokens correctly set.

How can the redirect 302 intercepted and redirected to the separately hosted UI app?

We´ve got the authorization working, so no login is required but calling the "copied app" does not work and results in "auth error" or "forbidden".

We already checked the documentation and other posts in here.

```
var cookie;
function relayRequestHeaders(proxyReq, req) {
  if (cookie) {
    proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', cookie);
  }
};

function relayResponseHeaders(proxyRes, req, res) {
  var proxyCookie = proxyRes.headers["set-cookie"];
  
  if (proxyCookie) {
    cookie = proxyCookie;
  }

};

const oOptions = {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    auth: 'user:pw',
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/dispatcher': '/dispatcher',
    },
    //cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
    onProxyReq: relayRequestHeaders,
    onProxyRes: relayResponseHeaders,
    logLevel: 'debug'
};

const wildcardProxy = createProxyMiddleware( oOptions );

app.use(wildcardProxy);
```

Any ideas on how to get that solved?

Thanks.

Update:
We tried as well to filter context paths which works but then it does not access the resources of the hosted webapp via express.

```
const oOptions = {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    auth: 'user:pw',
    logLevel: 'debug'
};

const wildcardProxy = createProxyMiddleware(['index.html', 'index.jsp', '!/resources/scripts/**/*.js'], oOptions );

app.use(wildcardProxy);
```

This is because we are proxying "/". How can it be achieved to only proxy the login and initial index.jsp but then using the resources of "webapp" and not of tomcat resources (e.g. *.js)? Is this possible somehow via the app.use to bind to certain files and paths?

Answer (score 1):

We got that solved. We just excluded certain files from being served by the target host.

```
config.json:
{
...
"ignoreFilesProxy": ["!/**/*.js", "!/**/*.css", "!/**/*.xml", "!/**/*.properties"],
...
}
...
createProxyMiddleware(config.ignoreFilesProxy, oOptions);
...
```

Next step was to change the Maven build, so that the UI modules are not served/packaged with the war-file in the local dev environment. We solved that by introducing two Maven Profiles to include or exclude the UI modules in the WAR-project.